# Unable to get DatabaseMetaData for Procedure from JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have 2 issues:
 I'm unable to get Procedure MetaData via JDBC
1.) if my procedure is inside a Package
2.) if the procedure is outside a package , but user is a non-schema owner , but has access to the Procedure

For (1) I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569843/jdbc-getmetadata-of-an-oracle-procedure-inside-package-in-a-schema)  link , but didn't work for me even when using Schema owner as the program user

Here's what my code snippet looks like:

```
 DatabaseMetaData metadata = conn.getMetaData();

        ResultSet rs = metadata.getProcedureColumns(
                    "PKG_TEST",
                    "ENTITLE",
                    "getUser",
                "%"); // Tried with null instead of % as well
```

Where getUser is a Procedure within PKG_TEST in Schema ENTITLE

The only thing that works for me is below:

```
 ResultSet rs = metadata.getProcedureColumns(
                conn.getCatalog(),
                null,
                "getUser1",
           null);
```

Where getUser1 is a Procedure outside any package but in the schema ENTITLE and the program logs into the database as ENTITLE

Are there any permissions required to access Database metadata of a schema?

Note that in the example above , it does not work if I login as a DB user that has access to the procedure , but is not schema owner.

Comment: `Note that in the example above that works if I login as a DB user that has access to the procedure , it doesn't work.`  I have no idea what you're saying here.  Did it work when logged onto the DB or not?

Comment: Oracle stores names in uppercase, so `"getUser"` should most probably be `"GETUSER"`

Comment: Susannah Potts , corrected the last line. Basically it doesn't work if I don't login as the schema user.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name ,when I created the procedure,i added quotes. And another procedure which was already in caps when created is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores names in uppercase

```
String p = "getUser1";

ResultSet rs = metadata.getProcedureColumns(
               conn.getCatalog(),
               null,
               p.toUpperCase(),
               null);
```